# How to convert list of dictionaries into bytes stream and load it to the database

Tags: postgresql, csv, upload, python-3.8, bulk

My standard way to run bulk upload of CSV files to Postgres database is to use copy_expert()
method:

```
cursor.copy_expert("copy %s from STDIN CSV HEADER NULL 'NULL' QUOTE '\"';" % (table_name), file=f)
```

Very often, before loading file to the database, I run some pre-processing of CSV file.
The results are always kept in list of dictionaries.
Following my standard way of loading I have to offload list of dictionaries to temporary CSV file and
only that file give to copy_expert() method as source of data.

What I would like to do is to replace source as a file with source as a some stream of bytes converted
from list of dictionaries. And then pass it to copy_expert() as a source.
I would like to exclude step of writing temporary CSV file and load data straight from memory.

Comment: Can you show how you are writing the files in the first place?

Comment: I'm not seeing this happen for the following reasons: 1) `copy_expert` is looking for a file or file-like object. 2) `COPY` is looking for field values(the value in the dict) in each row and will choke on the field names(the dict keys).  So at some point you will need to convert to a separated value(data only) format to get the data to work with `COPY`.

Comment: to jjanes. I do not quite understand your question. file=f in the code line is the file descriptor opened before copy_expert(). The file is common CSV file with header line.

Comment: to Adrian. Well, the dictionary mentioned here , just because it is common format I use for data in application. I understand that the values must be formed into binary stream . The keys of dictionaries should be stripped off. In the end copy_expert() is STDIN reading function - internally.
I guess I better rephrase the conditions. How to convert list of lists (rows) into a stream which will be accepted by copy_expert(). I have seen examples of using ByteIO or StreamIO modules, but cannot get my head around the exact syntax. May be it should not be copy_expert but some other function.